# showing 5 list items at a time with onClick and hide other items

Tags: jquery, css

I have no skills in jQuery, but need to accomplish my assignment. I have an unordered list of 15-20 items and want to display only 5 items at a time. On Click of a button, while others remain hidden. This is something like a pager. When 1-5 is seen, it should load 6-10 and 1-5 and 11-14 should be hidden. [I have HTML here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qrLh5p7/2/) (moved into question below).

Thanks in advance.

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
</ul>
<button onClick="next()">see more</button>
```

Comment: The site is meant for programming problems, not for expecting others to do your work. Please tell us what you have tried and what you are stuck with.

Comment: @ByteHamster yes I know but unfortunately I have not my workings available at the moment, I tried to achieve this using for loop but got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy, I guess you didn't search a lot...

you can achieve it in one line by `$('li:hidden').slice(0,5).show();`

[**Working demo here :)**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qrLh5p7/3/)

Edit: Updated fiddle

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qrLh5p7/4/)

Edit 2: Updated fiddle

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qrLh5p7/5/)

Comment: When all items has been displayed then clicking button this should again start from first 5 items, this part seems to be tricky to me.

Comment: yes this is good but what about the other which are also showing It should show only 5 at a time :(

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, let me try to explain **on page load** first five items should be shown, then user clicks on **see more** then it loads next 5 items and on 2nd click it should load the remaining items, when all finished then again clicking on **see more ** it should start from first five items again. hope this clarifies.

Comment: Absolutely not clarified :). Let's say: when page loads 1 2 3 4 5 are shown -> first click -> 1 2 3 4 5 are hidden AND 6 7 8 9 10 are shown -> second click -> 6 7 8 9 10 are hidden AND 11 12 13 14 are shown. Is that correct ? Do you want that on the second click 11 12 13 14 AND 1 are shown ? Or do you want to keep 1 2 3 4 5 shown after first click ?